# Reading the buffer property of each uploaded file, when there are multiple

Tags: javascript, express, multer

I am trying to upload multiple files to my server using `multer`. Even though I can read the `req.files` array, but can't access the `buffer` property of them. I tried `console.log`ging them, which only results in `undefined`.

This is my html (ejs) code:

```html
<form method="post" action="/send" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="file" multiple class="form-control" name="files" />
        </div>
        <div class="col text-end">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary w-100" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The route:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer({ dest: "uploads/" });

const indexController = require("../controllers/index.controller");

router.post("/send", upload.array("files", 5), indexController.send);

module.exports = router;
```

... the controller:

```js
exports.send = async (req, res) => {
    ...
    console.log(req.files); // [ { fieldname: 'files', ..., size: 1576 } ]
    console.log(req.files.map((f) => f.buffer)); // [ undefined ]
    ...
}
```

How do I read the `.buffer` property of each file, when there are multiple? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [the docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#file-information) and pay attention to the **Note** column where it mentions that `buffer` is only available when using `MemoryStorage`

Comment: You're absolutely right, @Phil. That was my bad. However, I suppose using memory storage isn't a good practice in prod environments, right?

Comment: That's entirely subjective

Answer (score 0):

I am using `memoryStorage` and still cant figure this out. I wont get the buffer file in the `Multers` filter option, only at the controllers level. I tried this code but I only get these fields (no buffer)

// RESPONSE (buffer is missing)

```
{
    fieldname: 'formImages',
    originalname: 'file-test.jpeg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg'
}
```

// CODE:

```
const multer = require("multer");
const sharp = require("sharp");
const sharpFilter = async (req, file, cb) => {
  const locationPath = `${process.env.UPLOAD_FOLDER + "/" + file.originalname}`;
  await sharp(file)
    .resize({
      width: 2000,
      height: 2000,
      fit: "cover",
    })
    .toFile(locationPath);
  cb(null, true);
};

exports.upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  fileFilter: sharpFilter,
});
```